# URL for new views in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've seen several MVC4 tutorials that show how to access the index URL for a view, but I can't seem to reach a new view that I add.

I can access my home index at:

```
http://localhost:3214/
```

But if I create a new view (let's call it "NewView.cshtml") I can't access it from

```
http://localhost:3214/NewView.cshtml
```

Where would it be?

The page inspector expects the page to be at:

```
http://localhost:4244/Home/NewView
```

But it isn't there.

**UPDATE:**

In the solution explorer the file is located at:

MyProject/Views/Home/NewView.cshtml

Comment: Where have you put the `NewView.cshtml` file in your project?`Views/Home/NewView.cshtml`? Have you created a action on the `HomeController` which return this `NewView.cshtml` as its view?

Comment: you need to add an action to point to a view. You should read more on MVC4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - So think of your Views as merely html files (although they are not) - i.e. they are purely for display purposes. But they are not static like normal HTMLs - they have code.

Hence its the controller and the route that you need to understand.

The route is what you type in the browser. For instance /Home/NewView will be translated to HomeController, NewView action if thats how you have configured it. The default view is {controller}/{action}/{id} so try `http://localhost:4244/Home/NewView/1`

Now to properly display and code NewView you need to go to your HomeController and add a NewView action. Like:

```
public ActionResult NewView()
        {
            return View(); // This will automatically display the NewView.chtml view from the Home (or Shared) folder in your Views folder
        }
```

Then go to your Routes (typically in your global.asax file and add it like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "SomeUniqueRouteName",
                "Home/NewView",
                new { controller = "Home" action = "NewView" }
            );
```

Then you can call it like `http://localhost:4244/Home/NewView` without the id cause you haev specified a route for it.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: The 2 Web API tutorials I've read show adding AJAX calls from a view where the view is not otherwise coupled to a controller (the index view in both cases). For my own reasons I like to access everything over AJAX (instead of a ViewBag, etc), so I wanted to just use a WebAPI controller. But it looks like I also need a non-Web API controller to setup/access the view.

Comment: They cant have an uncoupled view. If thats was the case then that was a simple HTML file that was creating AJAX requests from jquery or whatever. And if thats the case you serve it as an HTML file not a chtml.